# How do I configure an Azure Function to call the Microsoft Graph without using a user account?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

I have an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger that I am developing in Visual Studio 2019.  The intention is to have another application call the Azure Function, which will then call the Microsoft Graph to do some changes on users and groups.  I'm using the Azure Function to control what groups and users can be changed and to provide some business logic.

The function has an app registration in Azure, with an app secret so it can be protected.  However I try to submit a POST to the Azure Function, it never works.  I get a 404 when trying to use Postman.  If I use the Code + Test section in Azure Functions of the portal, I get "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'clientSecret')"

If I run the code locally and call it via Postman, it works, but of course there is no Azure authentication happening for this call.

I assume I have a authentication/configuration issue somewhere, but I do not know how to go about debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call .net Core Web API from other .net Core Web API projected by Azure AD, you use the [OAuth 2.0 Client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

Regarding how to configure it, please refer to the following steps:

**Register the web app**

[Register APP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)
Create Client secrets
[Configure permissions to access another web api.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis) (I use Microsoft graph for test)
[Configure an application to expose web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)(Add scope for the api)

**Register the client app**

Register Function APP
Create Client secrets
Configure permissions to access web API
[Configure known client applications for web API application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis)

In the Azure portal, navigate to your Web api app registration and click on the Manifest section.

1.In the Azure portal, navigate to your Web api app registration and click on the Manifest section.

2.Find the property `knownClientApplications` and add the Client IDs of the client applications.

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://www.tech-findings.com/2020/01/securing-function-app-with-azure-active-directory.html).